# How to set two MediaWiki tables to each be the width of half of the page?

Tags: html, css, mediawiki

So what I'm trying to achieve is two tables side by side where in total they cover the full width of the page and each table is half the width of the page. Currently I have two tables within another borderless 2 column 1 row table to align them side by side.

My code looks like this:

[image: Mediawiki Code snippet]

And this is what it yields:

[image: Side by side tables]

I would like for them to look something like the MediaWiki site where they have three tables next to each other that always take up the full page width and are all the same width regardless of window size except with only two tables. (Sorry for not linking to the site, I just joined StackOverflow and don't have enough reputation to post more than two links unfortunately)

I realize I could just make them a set width and sort of achieve what I'm looking for but that would be useless as far as users with different screen sizes wouldn't it?

Answer (score 3):

What you have is actually two inner tables wrapped inside an outer table.  Just adding the attribute `width="50%"` to the outer table cells should do the trick.  To keep the headings aligned, you may also want to use `valign="top"`, like this:

```
{|
| width="50%" valign="top" |

{| class="wikitable"
! Table 1
|-
| {{lipsum}} {{lipsum}}
|}

| width="50%" valign="top" |

{| class="wikitable"
! Table 2
|-
| {{lipsum}}
|}

|}
```

Comment: Ok so setting the outer table width to 50% did the trick with the width but the headings are misaligned. I tried using that  valign="top" but it did not work